# Default.png shows when applicationWillEnterForeground and using handleOpenURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm implementing an iOS application with the Facebook SDK which switches to the Safari browser for authentication and then back to the app using `application:handleOpenURL:`. The authentication works just fine, but when it switches back to my app, it shows the **Default.png** screen again for a beat. I'm not understanding why it's showing this since the application reports that it is entering the background and then back to the foreground and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is only called when the app first starts. How can I get a seamless transition back to my app without showing the Default.png screen again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this problem recently, and figured out a workaround. Read how I solved it here:

[iPhone App in suspended state, launched by URL, showing Default.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047692/iphone-app-in-suspended-state-launched-by-url-showing-default-png/7224448#7224448)

The summary is, if your exit point to Facebook is fairly predictable, create a Default-*scheme*.png (eg. Default-fb12345.png) screenshot.

Comment: Sounds great! Will give this a shot. Who knew?